# regex expression to find strings with two letters

Tags: regex

I need to find all strings where strings have letters "H" and "M" but no other letters before or after but other symbols are ok.
Valid strings:

```
HM
(HM)
&HM%
This is HM
HM are two letters
```

Invalid strings:

```
Marshmellows
asdfHMASDF
sfafhmasdf
```

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Presumably, when you say "before or after" you mean immediately preceding or following, which is not the same. All of your valid examples have `"HM"` but you do not state that `"H"` must precede `"M"`. What about `"MH"`? You say the strings must contain `"M"` and `"H"`, but not exactly one of each. What about  `"MHMM"`?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. Yes, I mean immediately preceding or following. "MH" or "MHMM" are not valid.

Comment: Your English is not the problem. Anyone can formulate a precise question in the language of their choice and simply translate it. The shortcomings of your statement of the question is not a translation problem. You must simply be more careful and precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex in ignore case mode:

```sh
/^(?:.*?[^a-z\n])?HM(?:[^a-z\n].*)?$/igm
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:.*?[^a-z\n])?`: Match an optional match of anything followed by a non-letter
- `HM`: Match `HM` (ignore case)
- `(?:[^a-z\n].*)?`: Match an optional non-letter followed by anything till end
- `$`: End

or else using look arounds:

```
/^.*?(?<![a-z])HM(?![a-z]).*/igm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/y3lx0A/1)

Comment: This works fine! I think I would never solved this :) Whats the difference with \bHM ? Sorry for dumb questions but I don't know regex at all.

Comment: `\bHM\b` will match complete word `HM` but it will fail to match `HM123`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
(^|.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])HM([^a-zA-Z0-9].*|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work (in python)

```
([^a-z]+)HM([^a-z])
```